# No menu items in Itunes's Account menu work. Can't sign into account

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I've recently migrated to a new mac, and since then I have not been able to sign into my account on iTunes. No items on the Account menu do anything when clicked. It also shows authorise this computer, and de-authorise this computer at the same time. Clicking any of these have no effect whatsoever.

When in the iTunes store, clicking on Account in the footer does nothing. When going through the Apple Music signup process in iTunes and click "Already have an account" does nothing. Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading and reinstalling iTunes fixed the issue.